# Perspective grid not appearing illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud, perspective

For some reason the perspective grid is not appearing when I click on the tool. I have even created a new document and selected the tool again and it still does not appear.

Comment: Check if its outside your artboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try going in view > Perspective grid > Show/ Hide

> Also SHIFT + COMMAND + I (mac)

and

> SHIFT + CTRL + I (windows)

See this [video](https://youtu.be/Uzig2s7pNss) for your better understanding.